# Programmatically hide/show a window in Linux

Tags: linux, window, hide, minimize

I've been searching all over the place for a solution to this.

How can I show/hide (or minimize/unminimize if you rather) Linux windows.

I'm interested in any solution in any language.

I use Debian, Gnome, Metacity and Compton composite manager if they're relevant

*Note: I tried using `wmctrl` but the `toggle,hidden` feature of `wmctrl` has been broken for a while and it's not been updated in two years so unlikely to work any time soon. The net is full of bug reports concerning this.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/):

```
$ xdotool search --name "Stack Overflo"
24415619
$ xdotool windowminimize 24415619
```

Basically, you first find a window (by title, by active state etc.), which gives you its ID. Then you invoke commands. There are many ways to find a window, see the manpage.

xdotool is available as a package in at lease Debian, Ubuntu and Fedora.

Note: Shamelessly stolen from this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/186748/how-to-hide-or-minimize-x11-window-from-console

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can try something like this.  It uses xdotool like @sleske suggested.  I bind the script to a mouse button using xbinkeys.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/tmp/last_active_window
if [[ -s $file ]] ; then
    xdotool windowmap `cat $file`
    cat /dev/null > $file
else 
    wid=`xdotool getactivewindow`      
    xdotool windowunmap $wid
    echo $wid > $file
fi
```

Comment: There is a typo: using _xbinkeys_.

Comment: I've been using a very similar script, with the `windowmap` line being `xdotool search --class terminator windowmap windowsize 1920 1080 windowmove 1920 0`. This works fine, but somehow, only for a bit. After 1-2 hours, or maybe after using it a  few dozen times? I dont know? ... it stops working. The window is effectively not unmappable anymore and I do not know how to fix it. TL;DR For a terminal, I'd suggest using Guake instead.

Answer (score 6):

you can hide and unhide windows using

```
xdotool windowunmap id
xdotool windowmap id
```

and you can get the id by

`xdotool getactivewindow`

this gets you the id for the current active window and if you want to search for the id, by application name or the pid

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible --name nameofapp
xdotool search --pid pid
```