# Hide Android Emulator menu bar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Is it possible to hide / auto-hide the Android Emulator's menu bar? The one shown below:

[image: Android Emulator Menu]

---

#### I've tried:

- Right click Android Emulator;
- Right click Menu Bar;
- Checking the three dots at the bottom;
- AVD Manager ("Device Frame" doesn't seem to help);
- Controls on top (`X` and `-` - closes and minimizes the emulator);
- Asking good old Google.

All without any success. Is it even possible to hide it?

PS:
The optimal behavior, imo, would be similar to the auto hide from Windows taskbar (or some sort of keyboard shortcut to make it reappear).

---

**Edit**
As mentioned in an answer, it might be possible to drag it if your using Ubuntu by holding Alt + dragging it. Although useful, that's still not the desired behavior - and it doesn't work for me as I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Have you found an answer by any chance? Couldn't find anything regarding this issue.

Comment: Not yet, @Martin

Answer (score 14):

You can use [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/):

First you should find the id of that window

```
$ xdotool selectwindow  //After you use this line you should select the window
12345678
```

And you just minimize it.

```
$ xdotool windowminimize 12345678
```

xdotool is available as a package in at lease Debian, Ubuntu and Fedora.

And you can install this tool with this line.

```
$ sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Credits:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26704369/3139930

Comment: This is brilliant! To do this in a single command, use 
`xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool selectwindow)`

Answer (score 11):

On Windows you may try windows-specific hack via 3rd party tool.

- Take WinSpy (https://sourceforge.net/projects/winspyex/)
- Follow instructions on screenshot

[image]

Comment: how to bring it back again ?

Answer (score 9):

I've found an alternative solution, you can move this sidebar by holding Alt key + click on the box. If you move the emulator, the sidebar will be placed on the default position.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu (didn't test it on Windows or Mac). You just have to hold Alt key and drag the sidebar with left mouse click.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and it doesn't work here. If I remember correctly that's an OS feature, so Ubuntu is the one doing the work here. I guess it would be useful to be able to drag it, but it's still not the desired behavior.

Comment: Yes, this should be possible. For me, moving the sidebar was enough to get a cleaner look. I'll try on windows 10 and let you know.

Comment: On some newer versions of Ubuntu, if "Alt"+drag doesn't work, try drag with the "Super" key (i.e. "Window" key) instead. (See https://askubuntu.com/a/1426306)

Answer (score 4):

For mac OS, I organised my window like this just pushing the whole emulator to the right side of the screen which remove the side menu out of the screen border.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

For people using windows and wanting to hide sidebar to make taking screenshots easier just drag the emulator to the edge of screen so that the side bar is hidden from view.