# Hide Android Emulator Tool Bar in KDE

Tags: linux, android-emulator, xdotool

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48644167/hide-android-emulator-menu-bar) on this site and from that question's solution, it works fine on my ubuntu gnome desktop with this command `xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool selectwindow)`.
But, it is not working on my other desktop which os is Manjaro KDE.
any solution for that?