# How to hide panel emulator

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, android-studio

[Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p301.png)
How to convert the second to the first? No matter how much I searched, I could not find anything about it
Thank you for helping me. I searched for a few days, but I couldn't find anything on YouTube and the Internet

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking to hide the menu on the first image, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48644167/hide-android-emulator-menu-bar) seems to cover some possible solutions.

If you're on a Linux machine, veysel suggests using `xdotool`. `xdotool` can be used on at least Debian, Ubuntu, and Fedora. You can install this using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Once installed, you'll need to get the menu id. Using the following command should return the menu id:

```
xdotool selectwindow
```

Finally, you can minimize the window using the following command, replacing `MENU_ID` with the menu id returned from `xdotool selectwindow`:

```
xdotool windowminimize MENU_ID
```

If you're on a Windows machine, Xtra Coder suggests downloading a 3rd party hack tool, such as `WinSpy`. You can find a link to `WinSpy` [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winspyex/). I have also included the screenshot found in the original answer which shows you'll need to drag the Finder Tool over the menu window and toggle it's `visibility` attribute found in the `commands` button.

[image]